# React making signup checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

We are making the necessary consent for membership registration with React. However, it is up to agreeing to the checkbox, but it does not work properly because it is re-rendered when the button is clicked. Any help would be appreciated.

```
enter code here
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState('disabled');
const [agree1, setAgree1] = useState(false);                                //회원정보 동의
const [agree2, setAgree2] = useState(false);                                //개인정보 수집 및 이용동의
const [agree3, setAgree3] = useState(false);                                //위치정보 동의
const [total, settotal] = useState(false);                                   //전체 동의
const [email, setemail] = useState("");

const buttonState = useCallback(() => {
  if((agree1===true)&&(agree2===true)&&(agree3===true)){
    settotal(true);
    setDisabled('');
  }
  else {
    setDisabled('disabled');
  }
},[agree1,agree2,agree3,total]);


 
useEffect(() => {
  buttonState();
}, [buttonState])

const totalchange = () => {
    if(total ===true) {                                                         //전체동의가 true라면 다시 클릭 했을때 전부 unchecked
        settotal(!total);
        setAgree1(!agree1);
        setAgree2(!agree2);
        setAgree3(!agree3);
    } else{                                                                     //그외(하나만 체크되 있거나 아무것도 없다면) 전부 checked로 만듬
    settotal(true);
    setAgree1(true);
    setAgree2(true);
    setAgree3(true);
    setDisabled('');
}
}


const clickFunction = () => {
  axios.get(`/signup/authNum?email=${email}`)
  .then(res => {
    if(window.confirm("인증번호 전송이 완료되었습니다")){
      history.push({
        pathname : '/registerauth',
        state : {state : res.data}
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```

}`enter code here`

Sorry for being awkward because this is my first question on stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the callback for the button click and why are you calling that function in useEffect?